# How to connect with Deltalake using Delalake python API using Azure Storage account connection string?

Tags: python, azure, parquet, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I want to get . parquet files stored in Azure Storage Account using Deltalake python API.
Say the location of the files are in this format,

```
location = "abfss://<container>@<StorageAccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filelocation>"
```

I tried the code given in this [documentation](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/12/22/natively-query-your-delta-lake-with-scala-java-and-python.html),

```
from deltalake import DeltaTable
dt = DeltaTable(location,storage_options = {connection_string =<SA_CONNECTION_STRING>)
dt.files()
```

When I try to run the code, it gives me the following error,

```
File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\workbook\.\main.py", line 59, in storage_deltalake
    dt = DeltaTable(x,storage_options=s)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\workbook\venv\lib\site-packages\deltalake\table.py", line 90, in __init__     
    self._table = RawDeltaTable(
deltalake.PyDeltaTableError: Failed to read delta log object: Generic MicrosoftAzure error: At least one authorization option must be specified
```

I checked with the connection string, it works correctly, so I am not sure why this is throwing an authentication error.

My problem statement is that I want to read the lastly modified parquet files inside the folder in Storage account.

Can anyone please help me solve this error or guide me to a different solution to solve my problem statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is a deltalake 0.6.0 regression bug (related to switching to object_store_rs).

There is a PR open which should restore existing functionality. https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/pull/787

Can you upgrade to deltalake 0.6.1 and see if that fixes your issue?